# Parsing value from Lottie JSON file

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, attachments, json

I am creating a scrollable Lottie component in WordPress using Advanced Custom Fields. The component consists of a sticky positioned div housing the actual Lottie player and a wrapper that interpolates the playhead position of the Lottie player from `0` (top of the wrapper hits top of viewport) to `1` (bottom of wrapper hits bottom of viewport).

For the implementation I envision, the wrapper would be sized based on the duration of the Lottie animation, along the lines of `style="height: calc(<?=$frame_count?> * 10vh)"`. The Lottie JSON file actually contains the duration of the animation but I can’t seem to access its contents. Here is what I tried so far:

```
$lottie_id = $row['lottie'];
$lottie_url = wp_get_attachment_url($lottie_id);
$lottie_json = json_decode(file_get_contents($lottie_url));
```

However, if I try to log the value of `$lottie_json` I get the following error messages:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto

file_get_contents(https://testing:8890/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/lottie.json): Failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Could anyone point me towards a solution? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: not really a WordPress issue.  Did you see this post though? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto